# Do I need to convert my intrinsic parameters after finding them in camera calibration (openCV)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration

I am building a robot that needs to know its trajectory using a monocular camera.

I have calibrated my camera using openCV and received its intrinsic parameters.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwpKvGfNwIc&lc=Ugy2J8ePPr2_ZuGVR4p4AaABAg.9kuFNVFPoID9kuNAPVCKkp).

One thing I don't understand is the units of his plots, how did he manage to get to meters?

I have read his code [here](https://github.com/niconielsen32/ComputerVision/blob/master/LiveCameraTrajectory/liveCameraPoseEstimation.py) and there is nothing to do with unit converting.
He claims to get his units to meters.

I rewrote most of the code, and all my plots are very disoriented. When I test it and walk 1 meter, it can say that I walked 8 meters.

I have received my intrinsic parameters in pixels from the calibration, I found the focal length in mm and the pixel size in micro meters from the [raspberry pi cam site](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html).

I think I need to convert my intrinsic parameters to meters using these two. Can't find documentation about this anywhere. would that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
distance (in meters) = (focal length (in mm) * object size (in pixels)) / (object size (in pixels) * pixel size (in um))
```

For example, if you have an object that is 50 pixels wide and the focal length of your camera is 5 mm and the pixel size of your camera is 0.0026 mm (2.6um), you can calculate the physical width of the object as follows:
(5 * 50) / (50 * 2.6 * 10^-6) = 0.96 meters

Keep in mind that this equation assumes that the camera is not tilted or rotated with respect to the object, and it also assumes that the object is at a fixed distance from the camera. If either of these conditions is not met, additional calculations are required.

This link could be useful for you too: https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html

Answer (score 0):

All the units in the camera matrix are in pixels, also the focal length.
The only calibration parameter that is in world units is the *baseline* (meters or mm, or whatever unit you may use).

So, where the baseline comes from? Well, when doing calibration with a chessboard, for example, you are usually asked to set the *square size*. Here is you chance to set it in world units (e.g. mm). An example is [here](https://github.com/decadenza/SimpleStereo/blob/20394dee2e7b8ea72d3758dca148abb5b7127a78/examples/003%20BuildStereoRig.py#L24).

Note that you may also leave it to 1 to get *adimensional* 3D reconstruction. This is probably why you are getting non-corresponding distances.

In your situation, you may also avoid to recalibrate by rescaling the baseline by the appropriate factor. Good luck!

**Note**
Pixel focal length is obtained by dividing the physical focal length (mm) by the real pixel size (mm).